# Best way to store multiple timestamps & numbers?

Tags: mysql, sql, pdo

I'm having trouble describing what I want so I'll try to illustrate it the best I can with arrays.

```
Array
(
    [user1] => Array(
        [title] => customtitle1
        [prefix] => false
        [worlds] => Array(
            [119] => 367
            [2] => 5
        )
        [time] => Array (
            100
            101
            102
            204
        )
        [last] => 119
    )
    [user2] => Array(
        [title] => customtitle2
        [prefix] => true
        [worlds] => Array(
            [119] => 367
            [2] => 5
        )
        [time] => Array (
            100
            101
            102
            204
        )
        [last] => 119
    )
)
```

I stored this in txt files but I moved on to SQL databases. How would I store this?

I only display 2 users here but it is more, the "worlds" array gets new values overtime (including new keys, so the length will change). Same goes for the "time" array, but only values.

```
username | title | prefix | 
user1    | bla   | true   |
user2    | bl2   | false  |
```

I don't know how I would go on implementing the worlds & time arrays. I would like to be able to sort these too.

Comment: Looks like you need to go and read about database normalization.

Comment: Yes. And that makes this question too broad.

Answer (score 0):

Keep entities separate is one goal of good [data modeling](http://www.agiledata.org/essays/dataModeling101.html#WhatIsDataModeling). Use one table to store one type of information, and another table to store another type, and relate them using [foreign keys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key) or [join tables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_entity). Per your example, you might want a structure like this.

```
users:
| id | username | title | prefix | last_world |
| 1  | user1    | bla   | true   | 119        |
| 2  | user2    | bl2   | false  | 119        |

worlds:
| user_id | worlds_id | other_id |
| 1       | 119       | 367      |
| 1       | 2         | 5        |
| 2       | 119       | 367      |
| 2       | 2         | 5        |

time:
| user_id | time |
| 1       | 100  |
| 1       | 101  |
| 1       | 102  |
| 1       | 204  |
| 2       | 100  |
| 2       | 101  |
| 2       | 102  |
| 2       | 204  |
```

These tables can be joined with a query like this:

```
SELECT 
  u.*, 
  w.worlds_id,
  w.other_id,
  t.time
FROM users u 
INNER JOIN worlds w
ON u.id = w.user_id
INNER JOIN time t
ON u.id = t.user_id
```

Constructing your database schema so that data is never redundant (e.g. you update a username one and only one place) and data is never incorrect in one place but correct in another is called [database normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).

Good luck!